# One method to access all resource values using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a resources file (MyResources.resx) that contains eg.

```
       Name   |   Value   |
    ----------|-----------|
      PageA   |   aaaaa   |
      PageB   |   bbbbb   |
      PageC   |   ccccc   |


  etc..etc...
```

(One of these for each page in the website. Roughly 100 pages)

In my class file I have the following:

```
public String GetDetails(String pageName)
{
    string detail = "";

    if (pageName == "PageA")
    {
        detail= MyResources.PageA;
    }
    if (pageName == "PageB")
    {
        detail= MyResources.PageB;
    }
    if (pageName == "PageC")
    {
         detail= MyResources.PageC;
    }
    etc...etc..(roughly 100 if statements)

    return detail;
}
```

Could somebody suggest a better way of doing this and explain how I would implement it?
Is reflection a good idea? If so how could I achieve changing this huge method into something like below?

```
public String GetDetails(String pageName)
{
    return MyResources.pageName;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the static property `ResourceManager` of the class `Resources` automatically generated in the namespace `Properties`:

```
public String GetDetails(String pageName) {
  return Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(pageName);
}
```

Comment: The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @dos what kind of project are you using? You've never heard about `Properties`? Try searching for it and you will know how to use it.

Comment: @dos please let me know if you have some thing new. I hope you know how to deal with `namespace` problem like this.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed return MyResource.ResourceManager.GetString(pageName)